# How to fix the stretching in my Normal Map?

Tags: normals, normal-map

I was following along this anvil tutorial, and I was to make a normal map of the mesh I made. I had sculpted it, and was ready to bake the sculpted, hi-res mesh with the low res mesh. When I followed the directions and baked, the normal map came out strange. The blue is there, but in the center are these weird stretches, and a lot of purple in the bottom.
Shown here:
[image: Stretching across the center]

I am not sure as to what I have to do to fix this. I went back to sculpting and smoothed out some stuff, and it did fix half of it, but the stretching was still there. I flattened the middle of the anvil, near the base. I am not sure if it is because of my sculpting. Maybe I sculpted too deep or too much. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Here is the link for my blend file.
http://www.mediafire.com/file/9k4836p9maf0uei/Anvil1.blend1/file

Comment: There are no streches with Plane.003, It works fine. You probably used a low poly mesh with a bad UV map.

Comment: @FFeller Oh, wait a second. I have to UV unwrap the low poy mesh as well?
my god i cannot believe i overlooked that.